# SQL JOIN with the same table

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I am trying to query in SQL and I can not resolve it.
I have a table **`tCliente`**:

[image]

What I want to do is a JOIN with the same table to find each pair of clients that lives in the same city.

I try to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.codiClien, c.nombreClien, c1.codiClien, c1.nombreClien, c.ciudadClien
FROM tCliente c
INNER JOIN tCliente c1 ON c.ciudadClien = c1.ciudadClien
```

and get this:

[image]

But I should get **this:**

[image]

I know I have to filter data, but I have tried many things and I can not find the solution.
Also, I tried to use **`GROUP BY`** but it is not possible. I wanted to group by **pair**, that is, something like this:

```
...
GROUP BY c.codiClien, c1.codiClien
```

But in doing so I get errors in the query. Could someone please help me? Thanks

**Note:**
When using **`ON`** in the **`INNER JOIN`**, I would like to know if it is "possible" to do that or should not do it, because the usual thing is to do `tb1.id = tb2.id`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must exclude itself on the inner join.

```
SELECT c.codiClien, c.nombreClien, c1.codiClien, c1.nombreClien, c.ciudadClien
FROM tCliente c
INNER JOIN tCliente c1 
    ON c.ciudadClien = c1.ciudadClien
    AND c.codiClien < c1.codiClien;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff due codiClien seems to be index. Yes, clever, Thank you.